# "No module named google.cloud" error when Python script is imported into a test, but not when run directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-python

Not sure if this is more google-cloud-related or pytest-related. See files below.

When I run either `python app/my_script.py` or `python -m app.my_script`, the script runs fine.

But when I run `pytest`, the line in the script `from google.cloud import vision` throws "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'".

I have tried unsuccessfully to add various package names into the requirements.txt file and/or run `pip install google-cloud` and `pip install google-cloud-language` with and without `--upgrade` flags. What steps can I take to overcome this error?

---

conftest.py: (empty)

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-vision
```

app/my_script.py:

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

def new_client():
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    return client

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = new_client()
    # etc...
```

test/test_my_script.py:

```
from app.my_script import new_client

# tests here...
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment and is pytest installed inside of it?

Comment: using an anaconda env `conda create -n my-env python=3.7` which has subsequently been activated. turns out pytest wasn't installed in the environment (and was maybe running from somewhere else), but then I did `pip install pytest` and the result is the same.

Comment: hmm it is possible that a fresh environment and `pip install --upgrade pip` may have solved the issue.